# Can't reproduce distance value between sources obtained with astropy

Tags: python, coordinates, astropy

I have two sources with equatorial coordinates `(ra, dec)` and `(ra_0, dec_0)` located at distances `r` and `r_0`, and I need to calculate the 3D distance between them.

I use two approaches that *should* give the same result as far as I understand, but do not.

The first approach is to apply [astropy](http://www.astropy.org/)'s [separation_3d](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html#astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.separation_3d) function. The second approach is to use the expression that gives the distance between two sources with spherical coordinates:

[image]

as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/833110/37846).

In the MCVE below, the values returned are:

```
91.3427173002 pc
93.8470493776 pc
```

Shouldn't these two values be equal?

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np

# Define some coordinates and distances for the sources.
c1 = SkyCoord(ra=9.7*u.degree, dec=-50.6*u.degree, distance=1500.3*u.pc)
c2 = SkyCoord(ra=7.5*u.degree, dec=-47.6*u.degree, distance=1470.2*u.pc)

# Obtain astropy's distance between c1 & c2 coords.
print c1.separation_3d(c2)

# Obtain distance between c1 & c2 coords using explicit expression.
ra_0, dec_0, r_0 = c1.ra.radian, c1.dec.radian, c1.distance
ra, dec, r = c2.ra.radian, c2.dec.radian, c2.distance
alpha_delta_par = np.sin(dec) * np.sin(dec_0) * np.cos(ra - ra_0) +\
    np.cos(dec) * np.cos(dec_0)
d_pc = np.sqrt(r**2 + r_0**2 - 2*r*r_0*alpha_delta_par)
print d_pc
```

Comment: I don't have the module installed, but throwing a suggestion. Are you certain `SkyCoord()` knowns exactly in what units you're feeding it the angle values?

Comment: It doesn't, which is why I explicit the units used using `*u.degree` and `*u.pc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a problem with coordinate systems, and the difference between **declination** (astral coordinates) and **polar angle θ** (spherical coordinates) :-)

Astral coordinates define **declination as north of the celestial equator**, while spherical coordinates define polar angle **θ as downward from from vertical.**

If you change your `alpha_delta_par` to account for this 90° difference by adding `np.pi/2` to all your declination terms, you get

```
alpha_delta_par = np.sin(np.pi/2 + dec)*np.sin(np.pi/2 + dec0)*np.cos(ra - ra0) +\
np.cos(np.pi/2 + dec)*np.cos(np.pi/2 + dec0)
```

Which gives the correct result: `91.3427173002 pc`.

<sub><sup>Turns out physicists usually use the symbol θ as the polar angle and mathemeticians usually use φ; I went with θ because I followed my heart.  [I'm not making this up I swear.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)</sup></sub>